# 3D Legend of a 3D plot

Tags: legending

```
P = RegionPlot3D[x^2/320.4995 + y^2/2292.1113 + (z - 30.078)^2/904.6860 \[LessSlantEqual] (1)^2, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, 0, 60}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.1]], Mesh -> 15]
```

I am curious to know if it is possible to have the legend of the above plot as the following:
[image]

Comment: `Legended[P, Placed[Style["The first sphere", 15], {.98, .5}]]`

Comment: Maybe I was not very clear. But now I have edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RegionPlot3D[##, Mesh -> 15, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    SwatchLegend[{Automatic},
     {Style["a sphere", FontSize -> 18, "FontFamily" -> "TimesNewRoman"]}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> 50, 
     LegendMarkers -> {RegionPlot3D[##, Mesh -> 5, 
        MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, Opacity[1], Gray], 
        PlotTheme -> "NoAxes"]}]] &[
  x^2/320.4995 +  y^2/2292.1113 + (z - 30.078)^2/904.6860 ⩽ (1)^2, 
  {x, -20, 20}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, 0, 60}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I get rid of the line on the legend? (This line is clearly visible when I increase the opacity). I would also like to change the font of the legend to Times New Roman. Would really appreciate any help. @kglr

Comment: @Math_student, please see the updated version.

Comment: It's perfect. Thank you so much! @kglr